# Issue in Json deserializaton to a map

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, json-deserialization

I have a question on Json deserialization,Problem is values of the "events" are not getting deserialized. I used apache cxf for the web service creation. input Json as follows,

```
    {"classList" : {
    "requestId" : "82334-adf86d-8bac8ef-289c",
    "events":[
        {
            "classType" : "Test",
            "externalId" : "973af2f8-820b-457b-89c2",
            "description" : "Test Class",
            "whenOccurred" : "2012040 3150000",
            "schoolId" : "affa1fa0-8dda-11e5-b165-08002706c445",
            "tagsAndValues" : "{ \"locationAccuracy\" : \"10\",\"attr2\" : \"value2\"}",
            "count" : "2"
         },
         {
            "classType" : "Test2",
            "externalId" : "45af4f8-87-4f42b-832abc",
            "description" : "Another Test Class",
            "whenOccurred" : "2012040 3150000",
            "schoolId" : "affa1fa0-8dda-11e5-b165-08002706c445",
            "tagsAndValues" : "{\"messageLength\" : \"135\",\"attrX\" : \"valueX\"}",
            "count" : "1"
          }
    ]
 }
}
```

The class i wrote for the deserialization as follows,

```
@XmlRootElement
public class ClassList implements Serializable {

    private String requestId;
    private List<HashMap<String, String>> events;

    public String getRequestId() {
        return requestId;
    }

    public void setRequestId(String requestId) {
        this.requestId = requestId;
    }

    public List<HashMap<String, String>> getEvents() {
        return events;
    }

    public void setEvents(List<HashMap<String, String>> events) {
        this.events = events;
    }


}
```

but the output is,

```
requestId: 82334-adf86d-8bac8ef-289c  
events: [{}, {}]
```

Is it possible to get the values of events to a list of maps like `List<HashMap<String, String>> events` without writing a "Event class" or without using library like jackson ? I'm new to this area please help me.

Comment: you have to use some library to parse the JSON. No matter which library it is.

Comment: can you try making the events as List<HashMap<String, Object>>? I suspect the string with tagsAndValues is getting parsed as well due to which the String, String in HashMap will not work.

Comment: I tried it for List<HashMap<String, Object>> as well but problem  still exists.